# Cypher: Problems with comparison

Tags: gwt, types, comparison, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to excecute a cypher query for a no4j database on gwt.

I stored in some nodes `int` values as property `detail`. If I'm using neoclipe right, I noticed now, that this values are stored in the database as `String` values.

In my query I have the following part which does not work:

```
START ... 
MATCH node-[:SomeTag]->intnode 
WHERE intnode.detail < 10
RETURN ...
```

and I get:

> Don't know how to compare that. Left: 15; Right: 10: Don't know how to compare that: Left: 15; Right: 10

So `intnode.detail < 10` does not work. I also tried this: `intnode.detail < STR(10)`, because I thought it will compare the hash values or ascii values, but I got the same error.

**EDIT:**

I read, that it is possible to set the `@GraphProperty` while storing data, but how can I do that in gwt?

I mean if I have a node and I could e.g. write

```
Object obj = (Object) 10;
node.setProperty("detail", obj);
```

How can I now tell neo4j, that obj is an int?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly focused on your initial question - not on the question you´ve added in the EDIT-part.
I just had a similar **problem** with a comparison inside the WHERE-part of a cypher query.  I tried to do something like

```
MATCH ...
WHERE value > 1
```

which caused an error message very similar to yours. After some testing I´ve found out that the query works, if I add single quotes. This is my **solution**:

```
MATCH ...
WHERE value > '1'
```

(note the quotes)
Ive also noticed, that this doesnt work with double quotes

I hope this helps you and/or anyone else who encounters this problem :)

Comment: Sonds good, but I actually don'T use this code anymore, so I am not able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intnode.detail value in stored as string , so you wont able to compare with integer value.

You have to do like this

START ... 
MATCH node-[:SomeTag]->intnode 
WHERE intnode.detail < "10"
RETURN ...